# Tridion Flickr ECL extension not working

Tags: 2013, ecl

I have downloaded and configured the Flickr ECL in my Tridion, Mountpoint has been created successfully. when i click the mountpoing, i am getting different error in my local machine and Tridion server.

Error from local machine: `WebUI/Models/ECL/Services/General.svc/GetList failed to execute. STATUS (404): Not Found`

Error from Tridion installed Machine:`Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

**ExternalContentLibrary.xml:**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
      <Configuration xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/ExternalContentLibrary/Configuration">

     <!-- Available logging levels: Debug, Info, Warning, Error -->
    <l:Logging Level="Warning" xmlns:l="http://www.sdltridion.com/Infrastructure/LoggingConfiguration">
     <!-- Additional supported attributes: Language="rfc1766 code" Locale="rfc1766 code". An example of an rfc1766 code is "de-DE" for German. /-->

    <!-- <l:Folder>Full path to logging folder, default is %TRIDION%/bin/log</l:Folder>-->
   </l:Logging>

    <CoreServiceUrl>net.tcp://machinenamehere:2660/CoreService/2013/netTcp</CoreServiceUrl>


<MountPoints>
    <MountPoint type="FlickrProvider" version="*" id="flickr" rootItemName="Flickr">
        <StubFolders>
            <StubFolder id="tcm:4-108-2" />
        </StubFolders>
        <PrivilegedUserName>TridionMachineName\MTSUSER</PrivilegedUserName>
        <FlickrApiKey xmlns="http://flickr.com/services/api">[hidden]</FlickrApiKey>
        <FlickrNSID xmlns="http://flickr.com/services/api">[hidden]</FlickrNSID>
    </MountPoint>
</MountPoints>

 </Configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out this useful blogpost from Mark Saunders, after the release of the Flickr ECL Provider, Flickr has made changes to their API URL, and so currently the extension you downloaded will not work as is, but with a small change you can be on your way again:

http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/flickr-ecl-http-to-https

### Update

Keep in mind that the connection to the Flickr APi is created from the CM server, and also that the ECL Provider currently does not take any proxy settings into account which might be required to connect to the internet on that machine.

First thing I would check is if you can access the Flickr API from the CM server, preferably not only in a browser or via a ping in a command prompt, but using some .NET sample code (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Bart, I have changed the code as guided in the post. However, now, i am getting error "Failed initializing the External Content Library with id flickr." any help?

Comment: @Jey Sounds like you need to debug it a little bit, there might be something as simple as a type in your NSID or API key, check them via the API explorer (for example https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photosets.getPhotos)

Comment: Looks like my NSID/Key provided in the config file is correct. Have tried to debug, got response for below. https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.getInfo . But from Tridion, still am getting "Initializing" error. when i change the http to https in "ExternalLibraryConfig.xml" file, again am getting "Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" error.

Comment: @Jey the URL used in the `ExternalLibraryConfig.xml` is a namespace, that you should not change. You only need to change the URLs in the `Api/Flickr.cs` class and recompile. If that doesn't work, then you need to debug it to see where what is going wrong exactly, could be all sorts of things network related or otherwise...

Comment: Hi Bart, which process i have to link to debug the ECL? I dont see any process running related to ECL in Tridion server. I could not find any related information in SDL Live Content also.

Comment: @Jey the Cm Service Host is your best bet always, if in doub't you can also add the dllhost and IIS processes from the CM server.

Comment: Hi Bart, When i debug the code, I am getting error in the linke "using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())" at flickr.cs file. The error is "unable to connect the remote server". But when i hit the request url in the bowser, i am getting response. Do you think this is an network issue? And when i try to ping "api.flickr.com" in command prompt, i am getting reply aslo.

Comment: @Jey keep in mind that the connection is made from the CM server, so you should check from there, sounds like a network issue of some sorts to me yes.

Comment: Hi Bart, I have tried to check the response using the .net code, getting proxy authentication error. So, used "request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;" in the code, I got the proper response for this URL "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getList&api_key=d6fd61f54b4ba29ea6e814288d29bdc9&user_id=129308671@N04" from the Tridion Server. So, I have added "request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;" in the FLickr extension and commented the Request.proxy = null; But still getting "Unable to connect to remote server" error.