# Failed initializing the External Content Library with id flickr

Tags: 2013, ecl

I know this is probably asked in a previous thread but I'm getting an issue integrating flickr with Tridion 2013 SP1

After downloading the package from SDLTridionWorld, I updated the `flickr.cs` file with HTTPS and placed the recompiled dll in `C:\ProgramData\SDL\SDL Tridion\External Content Library\AddInPipeline\AddIns\FlickrProvider` on the CMS

I created a flickr account with the api key and configured that in the `ExternalContentLibrary.xml`, restarted the server and accessed the mountpoint on Tridion.

I have validated api login are working on the CMS using https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photosets.getPhotos

After clicking on the Flickr mountpoint, I get the following error:

> 2015-03-05T18:24:03   TcmServiceHost  17  The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:10'.
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.EnsureInputClosed(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.CloseChannel()
>   The read operation failed, see inner exception.
>      at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>      at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
>   The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:10'.
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>      at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>      at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>      at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>      at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>   An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
>
> 2015-03-05T18:24:03    TcmServiceHost  17  One or more errors occurred.
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>      at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.UserContext.Dispose()
>      at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.EclService2012.Dispose()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceBehavior.ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Object instance)
>   One or more errors occurred.
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>      at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.MountPoint.<>c__DisplayClass53.<>c__DisplayClass55.b__51(Object param0)
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Server stack trace: 
>      at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.AddInPipeline.V2.AddInSideAdapters.ContentLibraryViewToContractAddInAdapter.Initialize(String mountPointId, String configurationXmlElement, IHostServicesContract hostServices)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>      at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.AddInPipeline.V2.HostSideAdapters.ContentLibraryContractToViewHostAdapter.Initialize(String mountPointId, String configurationXmlElement, IHostServices hostServices)
>      at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.MountPoint.GetContentLibraryForMountPoint(MountPointConfiguration config)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>
> 2015-03-05T18:24:03    TcmServiceHost  17  Failed initializing the External Content Library with id flickr.
>      at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.MountPoint.get_ContentLibraryContext()
>      at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.EclService2012.GetList(String parentItemId, Int32 pageIndex, EclItemTypes itemTypes, IEnumerable`1 basedOnSchema)
>      at SyncInvokeGetList(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
>      at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.TransactionSupportInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
>   One or more errors occurred.

Any idea why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tridion Flickr ECL extension not working](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8325/tridion-flickr-ecl-extension-not-working)

Comment: The ECL log file most likely contains a more detailed exception.

Comment: Please see the answer I have given here http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8325/tridion-flickr-ecl-extension-not-working/8326/#8326, if that does not help, can you check the ECL log file for a more detailed error or debug the ECL provider and edit your question to update it with the results?

Comment: Lars/Bart: I have updated the question with more of the ECL log. I have also validate that the api is working on the CMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. After validating the account info again with the following:

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.test.echo

I had the api key wrong.

Updating to what it shows in "api_key" it's now working :)